# What's the use of this empty function declaration in exec.c kernel source?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel

I see some empty functions in the Linux kernel file `exec.c` here:
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/exec.c#L235

But, some functions like `free_arg_pages` is again declared below here (with same protoype):
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/exec.c#L322

I am wondering why we have empty function and filled function with same prototype ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have the same function twice in a c file, so you need to look
at what `cpp` might be doing to manipulate the source. In this case, one version of the function is inside

```
#ifdef CONFIG_MMU
```

and the other is in the `#else` part.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `#ifdef CONFIG_MMU` construction around it. Only when `CONFIG_MMU` is unset, these functions should do something.